# synthetic motor oil life

Tags: oil

I have a Porsche Boxster with a "new" IMS bearing and have Motul 8100 X-cess 5W40 installed. Car is driven monthly & I am trying to determine should I change oil by millage or by time in engine.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If you follow the maintenance schedule, you shouldn't have an issue. Most maintenance schedules tell you to change it on *either* mileage or time, *whichever occurs first*.

Comment: See this as the topic is similar : https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/18834/10902

Comment: You can follow the schedule parameters as given or you could get your oil tested as per the other question...